# Redmine + Mercurial + Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, redmine

Is there an Issue Tracker plugin for Visual Studio 2010 to link tasks/bugs to specific issues existing in redmine project?

Comment: may be somebody is using a good solution that provide efficient issue tracking solution based on mercurial and redmine?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like there is a Visual Studio plugin for Redmine at present, although I did find a couple of posts on the [Redmine forums](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/boards):

> any interest in a visual studio plugin to view redmine issues?
>
> i've started working on one for myself. is anyone interested and, if you are, do you have any feature suggestions?

Later:

> i've actually already started work on something and gotten a decent amount done. I'll post it for download soon maybe! Any feature suggestions?

However, the last post was seven months ago, and there are no further posts from that user.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an extension to display Redmine issues as tasks in Visual Studio Task List.  Source code and the latest VSIX can be found at http://redminetasklist.codeplex.com